Elasticsearch is not loading from local docker installation on Mac
I'm trying to run elasticsearch locally, so I had installed docker then deployed elasticsearch image following this guide.
When starting it in docker I can see this info:

2024-05-20 21:04:48 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-20T18:04:48.744Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=org.elasticsearch.preallocate, --enable-native-access=org.elasticsearch.nativeaccess, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -XX:ReplayDataFile=logs/replay_pid%p.log, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-15934422589274926101, --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Xms3920m, -Xmx3920m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2055208960, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, --module-path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.node.Node","elasticsearch.node.name":"032a36703b3d","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}

Full log
And getting" "Cannot reach this page" when loading: http://localhost:9200/
I tried to change some values in

/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options

But I couldn't figure out the problem yet!
I had tried enabling:
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
or increasing the memory in:
Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
################################################################
##
## JVM configuration
##
################################################################
##
## WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. If you want to override the
## JVM options in this file, or set any additional options, you
## should create one or more files in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing your adjustments.
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/jvm-options.html
## for more information.
##
################################################################



################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## which should be named with .options suffix, and the min and
## max should be set to the same value. For example, to set the
## heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################


################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below here are considered expert settings. Do
## not adjust them unless you understand what you are doing. Do
## not edit them in this file; instead, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing your adjustments.
##
################################################################

-XX:+UseG1GC

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

# Leverages accelerated vector hardware instructions; removing this may
# result in less optimal vector performance
20-:--add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails; heap dumps
# are created in the working directory of the JVM unless an alternative path is
# specified
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# exit right after heap dump on out of memory error
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=data

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log

## GC logging
-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m

I also tried adding this line:

network.host: 127.0.0.1

in:

/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

didn't help too!

So you are basically trying to create a single node elasticsearch with all security settings are pre-done.

Starting in Elasticsearch 8.0, security is enabled by default. The first time you start Elasticsearch, TLS encryption is configured automatically, a password is generated for the elastic user, and a Kibana enrollment token is created so you can connect Kibana to your secured cluster.

If I were you, firstly I would clean all the containers. Then, as your reference documentation suggested, I would add
docker network create elastic
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4
docker run --name elasticsearch -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g" --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4

So you set above
-e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g"

This documentation is more extensive: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/docker.html

Thanks for your help, I deleted my old container and recreated it as u suggested, but still the same!

Can you please provide more information? Does your container run? If not, where is there error log? Can you please check "docker container logs your-container-name" or "docker inspect your-container-name" ?

The container is running, but I can't access http://localhost:9200 (as I had before)... uploaded the docker inspect and docker logs that you asked for: https://file.io/jjv1weJvDJVq

Log says: WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection. Did you try https://localhost:9200/ , I mean please use https instead of http.

same with https :(

It seems to me that your CA certificate is not properly set. Normally if you install an elasticsearch single node, it brings a CA certificate with it and convert it into .crt and .key. And it creates settings in elasticsearch.yml automatically. I would check the elasticsearch.yml and look for certificate paths and then look for them in container if they are really there. Here is some documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/docker.html#elasticsearch-security-certificates

The CA files are there - see attached screenshot https://file.io/8YBQX3P1kGb4
